# mysql_connect.. no connection and no error

Tags: php, mysql

This seems like it should be so easy but I am not getting an error or any result:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("phpexamplesite.db.4211592.hostedresource.com", "username", "password");
if(!$connection) {

    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

//2. Select a database to use

$db_select = mysql_select_db("username", $connection);
if(!$db_select){
die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
```

Any ideas?

THanks:)

sorry about that... I did put the query in:

```
// 3. Perform database query
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects", $connection);
            if(!$result){
                die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
            }

            //4. Use returned data

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row["menu_name"]. " ".$row["position"]. "<br />";
            }

            ?>

 <?php
        //5. Close connection

        mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

I'm not getting any error or results on the page...

Comment: that's because all works fine, the db connection and db select does not show nothing if it's ok, try adding some `query` to get result

Comment: @ristenk1 Also please stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead.

Comment: @Donut - oh, sorry... I'm trying to learn from a lynda tutorial.. is that why it doesn't work?

Comment: @ristenk1 do you have data in `subjects` table ?

Comment: @ristenk1 its ok to use mysql_* to begin with, these have been working fine for so many years. Can you try doing some print_r($row) in the while loop

Comment: @mgraph- I feel so dumb... I don't have any data in there... I'm using phpmyadmin... is there a fast way to add some data through the admin tool or do I have to do a mysql command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just don't have any result from the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be from a syntax error. You are missing a closing brace in the first code snippet in

```
if(!$db_select)
{
  die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error()); `
**}**
```

Try running your file from the command line through `php test.php`

Some servers (Apache) are configured to not output anything if there is a syntax error.